# C++ library to solve a system of trigonometric equations

Tags: library, c++

I have a pair of trigonometric equations in terms of cotangents, sines, cosines.  The variables are *u* and *t*, and I want to find the pairs of *u* and *t* which satisfy the equations, within the range 0 < u < 2pi, 0 < t < 2pi.

I've come across a lot of solvers and so on, but as far as I can tell they deal with polynomials and optimizations...  Most solves seem to be linear in nature.  I looked at Boost and ALIAS, but neither seem to do what I want to do. there doesn't seem to be much support for systems of trigonometric equations.  It doesn't help that as a newbie to C++, the library documentation is often quite incoherent to me.  I would like one with reasonable amounts of documentation and examples, since I really am not of the ability to just "do it".  Thanks.

Comment: What about the section [Solving trigonometric equation](https://www-sop.inria.fr/coprin/logiciels/ALIAS/ALIAS-C++/node84.html) in ALIAS-C++? How is it insufficient?